# Oracle joining tables

Tags: oracle, join

I have two tables in below format.

**TABLE1**

```
SMUN_FNL,START_DTE    
111     , 07/10/2011    
111     , 28/07/2015
```

**TABLE2**

```
SMUN,BASE_YMD    
111 ,30/09/2011    
111 ,30/12/2011    
111 ,16/07/2015    
111 ,01/02/2014
```

I Want to left join Table1 to Table2 so that for each record in TABLE1

```
TABLE1.SMUN_FNL = TABLE2.SMUN 
AND TABLE2.BASE_YMD <= TABLE1.START_DTE
```

i.e. For matching SMUN, it should pickup the **nearest** BASE_YMD **before** the START_DTE.

Table2 may or may not have a matching SMUN, or SMUN record with date before the START_DTE. 
The query should return same number of records as TABLE1. (TABLE1 LEFT Join TABLE2 I guess)

**OUTPUT**

```
SMUN_FNL|START_DTE |BASE_YMD    
111     |07/10/2011|30/09/2011    
111     |28/07/2015|16/07/2015
```

I put the join like this

```
TABLE1.SMUN_FNL = TABLE2.SMUN_ID 
AND TABLE1.START_DTE <= TABLE2.BASE_YMD
```

However it picks up 07/10/2011 date for both the records as both records satisfy `TABLE1.START_DTE <= TABLE2.BASE_YMD` condition.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How do you expect to get 111|28/07/2015|16/07/2015? The 28/07/2015 is not <= 16/07/2015.

Comment: You need to explain the business logic you expect will deliver the desired output

Comment: Andrey Belykh - table2.base_ymd should be same or prior to table1.start_dte. i.e. base_ymd <= start_dte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

**Assumptions**

- table1 SMUN_FNL and Start_date are UNIQUE: meaning the same date for the same smun_FNL would not be repeated.
- Start_DTE and Base_YMD are dates.  For the order by date logic (subtracting dates and returning the one with the "lowest" difference") to work.  if not they would need to be cast to dates.

What we do here us use a window function called row_number() against the 1st tables dates less the 2nd tables dates resulting in a numeric value in days, the lowest value of which would be the 1st row number in each group.  Then we just keep only the 1st row of each partition (SMUN_FNL, Start_DTE combo).

```
--test data
with table1(SMUN_FNL,START_DTE ) as (
SELECT 111, to_date('07/10/2011','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
SELECT 112, to_date('07/10/2011','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
SELECT 111, to_date('28/07/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') from dual),
table2 (SMUN,BASE_YMD) as     (
SELECT 112 ,to_date('07/11/2011','dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111 ,to_date('30/09/2011','dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111 ,to_date('30/12/2011','dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111 ,to_date('16/07/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111 ,to_date('01/02/2014','dd/mm/yyyy') FROM DUAL), 

--Begin part you need
cte as (
SELECT T1.SMUN_FNL
     , T1.START_DTE
     , T2.BASE_YMD
     , row_number() over (PARTITION BY SMUN_FNL, Start_DTE 
                          ORDER BY start_DTE-BASE_YMD asc) RN
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2  T2
 on T1.SMUN_FNL = T2.SMUN
and T1.START_DTE >= T2.BASE_YMD)

SELECT SMUN_FNL, Start_DTE, Base_YMD 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Yields:

```
SMUN_FNL START_DTE  BASE_YMD    RN
111     07-OCT-11   30-SEP-11   1
111     28-JUL-15   16-JUL-15   1
112     07-OCT-11               1
```

An outer apply join may be able to do the trick here as well but I'm not sure of your oracle version and window functions have been around for a few years now.

Comment: Updated, needed to include SMUN_FNL as part of partition logic for window function and added sample data to show what happens when table 2 match not found.

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on the comment below "I need the nearest table2.base_ymd prior to table1.start_dte from table2" and a new business requirement "Table2 may or may not have a matching SMUN, or SMUN record with date before the START_DTE. The query should return same number of records as TABLE1":

```
SELECT t1.SMUN_FNL,
  TO_CHAR(t1.START_DTE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS START_DTE,
  TO_CHAR(t2.BASE_YMD, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS BASE_YMD
FROM 
  TABLE1 t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    TABLE2 t2
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT t1.SMUN_FNL, t1.START_DTE, MIN(t1.START_DTE-t2.BASE_YMD) AS MIN_DIFF
      FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
        ON t1.SMUN_FNL = t2.SMUN 
        AND t2.BASE_YMD <= t1.START_DTE
      GROUP BY t1.SMUN_FNL, t1.START_DTE
    ) t3
    ON t2.SMUN = t3.SMUN_FNL
  ) t2
  ON t1.SMUN_FNL = t2.SMUN
    AND t2.BASE_YMD <= t1.START_DTE
    AND t1.START_DTE = t2.START_DTE
    AND t1.START_DTE-t2.BASE_YMD = t2.MIN_DIFF
```

Comment: I need the nearest table2.base_ymd prior to table1.start_dte from table2

Comment: Bit sceptical about inner join. I have edited answer with more business logic. Don't we need left join?

Comment: Yes, you do need an outer join. I updated my answer according to your updated question.